# ¿Donde me falta la propiedad connectionSting?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Tengo una duda, ¿a que se debe este mensaje y como lo resuelvo?; "No se ha inicializado la propiedad ConnectionString".

En mi código hay  una variable que almacena una cadena para mi conexion, y quiero hacer uso del mismo pero me ha marcado este mensaje. No estoy seguro en donde me este equivocando en el código, espero y me puedan ayudar por favor!

**Aquí solo agreego como creo la variable de conexión.**

```
      public partial class AuthorBrowser : System.Web.UI.Page
 {

private string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PUBG"].ConnectionString;


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) ...

private void Metodo() ...

protected void crearconexion(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   ///Imagina que hay código como si fuera matrix
  ///
  ///
  //

        string conexion = "Data Source ="+Servidor+"; Initial Catalog ="+BD+"; Integrated Security = SSPI";

        Session["conexion"] = conexion;

 }
```

**Aqui quiero hacer uso de esa conexion, pero me marca el error!**

```
   protected void Gridview1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    {
        SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection((string)Session["conexion"]);
        {

            sqlCon.Open();
            string SQLTable;
            SQLTable = "SELECT  * FROM empleados ";


            SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(SQLTable, sqlCon);
            DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
            sqlDa.Fill(dtbl);
            GridView1.DataSource = dtbl;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            sqlCon.Close();
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Ya has intentado depurar paso a paso? por ejemplo, has visto si esto está recibiendo el valor deseado Session["conexion"] = conexion;

Comment: Hola, gracias por comentar. Ahora lo estoy haciendo, respondo en breve. <3